# How to combine elements and attributes?

Tags: xml, xsd

I'm reading the [W3school about XSD](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/schema_intro.asp) and what I'm missing is how I specify common elements AND attributes within a complex type. I suppose it goes like this

```
<xs:element name="character">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:attribute name="lang" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
    <xs:all>
      <xs:element name="firstName" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="lastName" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:all>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

but I can't verify this and hope you can clarify. Alternatives I can think of: attribute into `<xs:all>` or use of `mixed="true"`.

Additionally, if you know where I can check my schemes for validity, please drop a link in the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there, but (perversely) the attributes have to be specified last, that is, after the `xs:all`.

I'd strongly recommend getting a book on XML Schema to best understand the concepts. W3Schools is good at presenting things in a simple way, but if you only have a simple understanding, you'll never understand the error messages.

Also, I'd recommend investing in a development tool such as oXygen for editing and validating your schemas.

Comment: Thanks for your kind recommendations. But since this is only for a small personal project, I'll currently not invest :)